# Amazon Kinesis duplicating data after shard rescaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

We have a following case:

- Initial 10 shards on stream, reader running.
- We rescaled to 20 shards via console, our app doesn't have
  appropriate logic to handle shard termination. Application was unable to consume data from new shards
- Rescaled back to 10 shards, no effect, consumer restart didn't help
- after 3-4 hours we deployed a fix that had valid shutdown code in a processor:

  `@Override
      public void shutdown(ShutdownInput shutdownInput) {
          if(ShutdownReason.TERMINATE.equals(shutdownInput.getShutdownReason())) {
              try {
                  shutdownInput.getCheckpointer().checkpoint();
              } catch (InvalidStateException | ShutdownException e) {
                  log.error("Checkpoint failed", e);
              }
          }
      }`

In result, we've seen data stared to flow through processor. in a backing Kinesis table value for `checkpoint` field was updated to `SHARD_END`. (but `checkpointSubSequenceNumber=0` as before).

After around 24 hours we've seen data which is one day old started to flow through our processor again (I am sure). GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds went to 80M+. Data sent was already processed day ago (checked in logs/etc).

**Did we mess up to correctly shutdown shard?** Will we end up having fake-received this data after 24 more hours? Is there any explanation for that behavior?

And yes, table for leases now has 30 records: 20 for shards 10-29 with checkpoint=SHARD_END and 10 for later shards. I've removed previously existing 10 records for 0-10 shards while trying to force restart processing. I am concerned that lease_counter is growing for dead shards.
Writer didn't stop during all this time.

Comment: we found out, that just before we started to receive duplicate data we had lease lost on almost all shards (fake, actually, network probably). And then client was reinitializing shard leases with trim_horizon, and that certainly caused us having received data from new shards second time. 

`22:55:16,637 [LeaseRenewer-0003] ... Worker ... lost lease with key shardId-000000000036

22:55:32,590 [Thread-21] Worker  Created new shardConsumer for : ShardInfo [shardId=...030,...], checkpoint={SequenceNumber: TRIM_HORIZON,SubsequenceNumber: 0}]`

previously leases were marked as LATEST

Comment: after investigating `https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-learning/blob/master/src/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/samples/stocktrades/processor/StockTradeRecordProcessor.java` found that we are not making checkpoint on message processing. So assumption is, we were reprocessing items from new shards (not those that existed before) after lease lost. Added checkpointing and investigating further.

Comment: fixed code with correct checkpointing. all performed well.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was: 
No checkpointing after normal records processing. We had LATEST checkpoint by default. Until we started to reshard we never thought that we might loose some data (e.g. during deploy if we put existing instance down before the new one is up).

No checkpointing on shutdown().

AWS has docs for v1 and v2 client, but only describes everything in v1. So, be aware and check docs for v1 as well (this https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-learning/blob/master/src/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/samples/stocktrades/processor/StockTradeRecordProcessor.java explains pretty much).